# Is it better to add an attribute to a class, or call a function 3 times?

Tags: perl, class, time-complexity

I am working in perl. My main module has many attributes in it (about 30). I need to call a function that is  O(n) where n is currently 9 and I don't see it getting bigger than 20 in the next 5 years.

My question is this: I will need to call this function (determine_values) either 3 times, or I can call it once in new and stash the value returned in the object, and use that object 3 times.

I am unsure if it is better to trade off time complexity (O(n)) (but called three times), or to use additional memory ( the function returns an array ref to an array of at most n items)

Comment: Could the value change between the initial and subsequent calls?

Comment: you could [`use Memoize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Memoize) to cache the result of your function call and avoid storing the result in an attribute of your class. Assuming that the value is constant for all three function calls.

Comment: Either I'm misunderstanding you or you don't get the hang of Big O notation. `O(9)` is the same as `O(1)`, which means fixed time, regardless of the size of the task. `O(n)` means linear time, i.e. the time taken is broadly proportional to the size of the task. You have several values in your question. It is clear that `n` is 9 to a maximum of 30, but I don't get what `n` *means*. You are creating objects with about thirty attributes; that's fine, but what is `n`?

Comment: The value is consistent between calls. 

When I said O(n), I mean where n is the number of values I have to iterate over in the function. This value is currently 9, but that will change in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be inordinately worried over a very simple function of your class. A program should be written in the clearest and most obvious way possible, and then if you find in testing that it is too slow, you start profiling it to find where in your code it is best to try to gain some speed.

You are concerning yourself about optimisation far too early. Get your program going first, and then look at optimising it if necessary. Even if you do have to speed things up, I doubt if improving the efficiency of some attribute accessors is going to turn the tables.

You haven't explained your project in any detail, but I don't see that there is a choice between memory usage and time complexity. If necessary you can use some space to cache values that save you looking them up again, but the complexity doesn't change.